# Application hangs and crashes (issue with 4.3.5)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found)
```

I have tried deleting the 4.3.5 (8L1) folder and reimport however I keep getting the same error when I click a certain button (get local address book)

What is going on?

Comment: If your app is crashing, please read/post the crash message. The warning shown above is not the crash message. Hook up your 4.3.5 device and start the app on your device with xcode and wait for the crash. Then analyze the crash report. Then rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add Framework in your xcode project..
**libxml.dylib**
Add this one in your project...

Comment: But my application worked fine before. Why it stopped working?